# How to call a function when the block visibility changes?

Tags: javascript

When the user clicks on the map, the address_box code block becomes visible.

```
<div id="adress_box" style="visibility: hidden">We are looking for delivery to <span id="address_confirm"></span></div>
```

How do I make the code below run when the visibility changes to visible?

```
alert('div is  display!!!');
```

so far, I have only achieved that when the page loads, a similar code is executed:

```
<div id="adress_box" style="visibility: hidden">Ищем доставку по адресу <span id="address_confirm"></span></div>

<script>
let element = document.getElementById('address_confirm');
let cssObj = window.getComputedStyle(element);
if (cssObj.getPropertyValue("visibility") == 'visible') {
    alert('div is display!!!');
}
</script>
```

Comment: Attach the `if` statement to the `onClick` event that is used for the map. Add it to the function that displays the `address_box`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we click on the map, with changing visibility changed div's text.
Much easier listen text changing in the div.

```
<div id="adress_box" style="visibility: hidden">Ищем доставку по адресу <span id="address_confirm"></span></div>

<script>
document.getElementById("address_confirm").addEventListener("DOMSubtreeModified", function() {
  alert('div is display!!!');
});
</script>
```